# Selecting second column (FileReader)

Tags: java, csv, multiple-columns, bufferedreader, filereader

I'm looping csv. I have two question:

1) I'm selecting second column by name like

```
if(tab[1].equals("Col2")
```

I don't want to put the name of column. I want to select just second column.

2) how to skip first line (header)

Here is sample of code to looping csv:

```
String csvFile = "C:\\test.csv";
BufferedReader br = null;
String line = "";
String cvsSplitBy = ";";

try{
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] tab=line.split(cvsSplitBy);      

        int tmp;
        if(tab[1].equals("Col2")){                

            tmp = Integer.parseInt(tab[2]);

                for(int i=0;i<tmp;i++){  
                   // TO DO
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, you could try opencsv lib.

Comment: 1) You are not selecting column by name, you are selecting the second column with `tab[1]`, and then comparing it to `"Col2"`. Or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: @njlarsson - correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to make use of `CSVReader` for this, which provides lot of APIs for processing your csv files. Here is a complete working code, ofcourse, without exception handling.

```
String csvFile = "C:\\test.csv";
CSVReader reader;
String[] nextRow;
char cvsSplitBy = ';';

try {

    //Last argument will determine how many lines to skip. 1 means skip header
    reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFile), cvsSplitBy, CSVParser.DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHARACTER, 1);

    while ((nextRow = reader.readNext()) != null) {

        if(nextRow.length > 2){
            //nextRow[1] will always give second column value
            int tmp = Integer.parseInt(nextRow[1]);
            for (int i = 0; i < tmp; i++) {
                // TO DO
            }
        }
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Did you use `CSVReader` or your `BufferedReader` itself ?

Comment: Im changing to CSV.....can you please show me how should look while loop now? while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)

Comment: I have added complete working code now.Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: one more question: I have line: tmp = Integer.parseInt(tab[2]);

can you show me also how to write now using CsvReader?

Comment: I have already added that to the code. nextRow is just a String array containing all the values. So you can get it by `int tmp = Integer.parseInt(nextRow[1]);`

Comment: later into my code to I have FileWriter & BufferedWriter. Should I also change it t other methods?

Comment: If you are using them to write to a csv file then you can explore the `CSVWriter` as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131165/discussion-between-4est-and-a-k-desai).

Comment: when I run code a got something like: 
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "line 2"......
this is probably from: if(nextRow.length > 2).........
csv looks like below: ........
 File Name;Grid name;Column Number 
 2_grids_pd;grid;5 
 2_grids_pd;grid;7 
 2_grids_pd;grid;2

Comment: That must because your second column should be a number. So as I said, you would have to handle those exceptions while reading the file and processing the data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/), and its `CSVParser`.

The first line is considered to be the header and is skipped (`withFirstRecordAsHeader()`) , the "columns" of each record can be accessed with their index (`get(int)`) .The  indexes are 0-based .

Just adapt the charset and `CSVFormat` to your needs.

```
CSVParser parser = null;

try {

    parser = CSVParser.parse(new File(csvFile), Charset.forName("UTF-8"),
            CSVFormat.RFC4180.withFirstRecordAsHeader());

    List<CSVRecord> records = parser.getRecords();

    for (CSVRecord record : records) {

        int tmp = Integer.parseInt(record.get(1));

        for (int i = 0; i < tmp; i++) {
            // TO DO
        }

    }

} catch (IOException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

} finally {
    try {
        parser.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

With [univocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) this becomes a piece of cake:

```
CsvParserSettings parserSettings = new CsvParserSettings(); //many options here, check the tutorial.
parserSettings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true); //header is extracted and not part of the result
parserSettings.selectIndexes(1); //select 2nd column (indexes are 0-based)
CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(parserSettings);
List<String[]> allRows = parser.parseAll(csvFile);
```

Note that this will work even if some of the rows are empty of have just one column, whereas all other solutions posted here will fail unless you handle such situations by yourself.

Not only this involves WAY less code (and complexity), the parser is also ~4 times faster than Commons CSV, and ~3 times faster than OpenCSV.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library, it's open-source and free (Apache v2.0 License)

Comment: hi, under csvFile, can I put:  String csvFile = "C:\\test.csv" ?

Comment: No you need to have: File csvFile = new File ("c:/test.csv");